# How to response an error in apollo-graphql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I want to response an error message when email already exists. I used `reject(message)` in resolve function, and I got an error message what I want in graphiql. But my console always shows an error, I hope the console doesn't show error. How can do?

resolve:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      let results = await User.find({ email });
      if (results.length > 0) {
        reject('用户已存在(｡ì _ í｡)');
      } else {
        let user = new User({
          email,
          password: await b.hash(password, 10),
          date: Date.now()
        });
        resolve(user.save());
      }
    });
```

index:

```
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
    schema,
    context: {
      db
    },
    formatError: error => {
      return error;
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I set `export NODE_ENV=production` and the error is resolved.